# Como não repetir dados nessa query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Fiz essa query, que irá compor uma view.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     US.EMPLOYEESTATUS
    ,US.EMPLOYEEID
    ,US.EMPLOYEEFIRSTNAME + ' ' + US.EMPLOYEEMIDDLENAME + ' ' + US.EMPLOYEELASTNAME AS FULLNAME
    ,US.GRADE
    ,SO.SOLICITATIONID
    ,SO.DATEFINANCING
    ,SO.MANUFACTURER
    ,SO.MODEL
    ,SO.CHASSI
    ,SO.VALUEPROPERTY
    ,SO.VALUEGRANTED
    ,SO.STATUSSOLICITATION
    ,PY.PAYMENTSTATUS
    ,PY.VALUEPAYMENT
    ,PY.DATEPAYMENT
    ,MAX(PY.NUMBERSEQUENCE) AS SEQUENCE
    ,MAX(PY.DATEPAYMENT) AS DATEPEYMENT


FROM
    [dbo].[USER] US 
    INNER JOIN SOLICITATION SO ON US.USERID = SO.USERID
    INNER JOIN PAYMENTS PY ON US.USERID = PY.USERID AND PY.SOLICITATIONID = SO.SOLICITATIONID

WHERE
    PY.PAYMENTSTATUS IN('QT', 'PG')

GROUP BY
     US.EMPLOYEESTATUS
    ,US.EMPLOYEEID
    ,US.EMPLOYEEFIRSTNAME
    ,US.EMPLOYEEMIDDLENAME
    ,US.EMPLOYEELASTNAME
    ,US.GRADE
    ,SO.SOLICITATIONID
    ,SO.DATEFINANCING
    ,SO.MANUFACTURER
    ,SO.MODEL
    ,SO.CHASSI
    ,SO.VALUEPROPERTY
    ,SO.VALUEGRANTED
    ,SO.STATUSSOLICITATION
    ,PY.PAYMENTSTATUS
    ,PY.VALUEPAYMENT
    ,PY.DATEPAYMENT
```

Esse é o resultado do select
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que pelo screenshot acima, as solicitationid de número 7378 e 7380, se repetem 3 vezes, isso se dá ao fato de ter 3 datas de pagamento distintas. Tentei dar um `MAX(PY.DATEPAYMENT)`, mas isso não resolveu, conforme podem ver na query. A pergunta é:

Como eu faço para trazer nessa query, um registro de cada e na tabela de Payments eu trzer sempre a última data paga(PG) ou quitada(QT). Esse último será apenas um só. O resultado deveria ser 7 registros e não 11, como está.

Comment: Ali no seu script você utilizou `MAX(PY.DATEPAYMENT)` mas não removeu o mesmo do `GROUP BY`... E existe outra coluna que pode dar problema que é a `SEQUENCE`, mas com esse campo você fez certo, utilizou `MAX(PY.NUMBERSEQUENCE) AS SEQUENCE` e tirou ele do `GROUPBY`

Comment: Você tem razão. Quando adicionei o DatePayment esqueci de removê-lo do group by e do select. Responda esse comentário, que eu marco sua resposta.

Comment: Que bom que lhe ajudei! E continue fazendo scripts bem organizados assim, raro encontrar scripts assim por aqui! Isso ajuda muito na hora de dar um help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ali no seu script você utilizou `MAX(PY.DATEPAYMENT)` mas não removeu o mesmo do `GROUP BY`...

E existe outra coluna que pode dar problema que é a `SEQUENCE`, mas com esse campo você fez certo, utilizou `MAX(PY.NUMBERSEQUENCE) AS SEQUENCE` e tirou ele do `GROUPBY`.